# Using pandas Data Frames, how to find repeated values in particular column?

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a Data Frame with multiple columns. I did dataFrame.groupby:

```
data_count = data.groupby('member_id')
```

I am unable to figure out next step to find rows with same member_id.

I want to find count of repeated rows per category in 'member_id'.
e.g.
memer_id
1
1
1
2
2
The output should be 
member_id         Count
1                         3
2                         2

P.S: I can think of thousands of workarounds like writing  loops and all. But what is the shortest way of doing this?

This very basic Question . I referred to stackoverflow and the pandas documentation but it seems when it comes to python, Google search and documentation don't help much even to find basic functionality.

Comment: `data.reset_index().groupby('member_id')['index'].apply(list)`

Comment: I'm not clear on what you actually want to end up with. Wen's answer will give you a series of lists of row identifiers, one per member_id. Or are you looking for simply all rows that are duplicated (i.e. you could use `data.duplicated()`? Or do you want the actual rows - e.g. a list of DataFrames, one per member_id? Or just an iterable of DataFrames, one per member_id?

Comment: Thanks for mentioning data.duplicated() it is helpful in a way.
I want to find count of repeated rows per category in 'member_id'.
e.g.
memer_id
1
1
1
2
2
The output should be 
member_id         Count
1                         3
2                         2

Comment: Ah, in that case `.groupby()` is more complicated than you need. You can just use `.value_counts()`. I've made it an answer.

Answer (score 0):

`value_counts()` will do what you want if you just want the counts of the different values that appear for `member_id`. That is, use

`data['member_id'].value_counts()`

By the way, if you are curious how to to achieve this with `groupby`, you could use `.aggregate('count')` or just `.count()`, like so:

`data.groupby('member_id').count()`

or

`data.groupby('member_id')['some_other_field'].count()`

if you want to avoid redundantly counting *all* the other fields.